# Magento - How to change URL of a link

Tags: php, magento

Basically I need to change an URL to a page that does not exist in the admin panel -> CMS -> Pages

The link is http://www.mywebsite.com/contacts

I know how to edit the contents of this page, since it's located at "/app/design/frontend/shopper/default/template/contacts" but the issue is that I want to change the URL to http://www.mywebsite.com/kontakt

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use a framework?

Comment: I use Magento 1.8.1 (newest version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never **Edit Core Magento files** in any case. If you change the **config.xml** located at `app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/etc/config.xml`, all your changes will be lost when your Mage version is upgraded.

1) Make a new module and change frontname for your contacts page

OR

2) Make a new CMS page having URL key **kontact**, content having Contact form block, make a new URL rewrite and redirect **contacts to kontact** and you're done

Comment: Okay @Slimshadddyyy, the second option worked fine. However I feel the first one is best practice. When I edit the frontname in the core files, it works just fine! But when I copy the 'Contacts' module to the local dir, and change frontname - it does not override.. how come? Basically I copy /app/code/core/Mage/Contacts to /app/code/local/Mage/Contacts and edit the config.xml in local.

Comment: You must not copy Mage folders and its files in your local and start working.Make a seperate module which overwrites Mage_Contacts and then perform your changes.Also the best method would be working with .htaccess
If the method worked for you pls upvote the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I made a seperate module and did overwrite the Mage_Contatcs. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that, just update line 40 in `app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/etc/config.xml`

from <`frontName>contacts</frontName>`

to `<frontName>kontakt</frontName>`

***try to remove cache and if your compilation is enble then try to recompile that***

**EDIT**

***Please override contact module after it test in core file and move into local folder***

[image: See Image]

Comment: do you really think editing the core Mage files is a good practice ?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy no after it works you can override contact module

Comment: Why would it not work if you are overriding core files ? Rather make a local module.

Comment: @Keyur Shah, when I edit the frontname in the core files, it works just fine! But when I copy the 'Contacts' module to the local dir, and change frontname - it does not override.. how come? Basically I copy /app/code/core/Mage/Contacts to /app/code/local/Mage/Contacts and edit the config.xml in local.